# CSS transform: multiple divs, same CSS, different outcomes

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a number of parallelograms with the same skew positioned horizontally.
The first one by itself is perfect, as I add more divs, the skew seems to increase with each one. 
I've tried this with images (transform: rotate()) with the same result.

I have one class to create them.

**CSS:**

```
.parallelogram-1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0px 40px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  background: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="para">
  <div class="parallelogram-1">
  <div class="parallelogram-1">
  <div class="parallelogram-1">
</div>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donfiftyboise/0u14evtx/2/)

Your help would be much appreciated! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close your divs.

```
<div id="para">
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
</div>
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0u14evtx/4/)

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us! :P

Answer (score 1):

Your divs are getting skewed additionally, as you didn't close the ones before. Close the divs:

```
<div id="para">
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is just you forgot `</div>` at the end of each declaration!

```html
<div id="para">
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your divs. Also if you wanted them to be side by side, make them inline-block or they will be each block on its own line.

HTML:

```
<div id="para">
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
  <div class="parallelogram-1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parallelogram-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  background: red;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0u14evtx/8/